# Numerical aggregate of unique column value by particular value with multiple groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, etl, data-analysis

1. Consider a pandas dataframe

[image]

Numerical aggregate of unique cam_id opened by user on same value based on r_no
 and output should be like

[image]

Suggestions 
(I tried group by seems i am increasing the complexity i have million rows)

```html
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['r_no'] = [1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2]
df['user'] = ['sam','sam','sam','sam','peter','jack','jack','Kris','peter']
df['value'] = [76,76,7,8,8,2,29,2,8]
df['cam_id'] = ['ab','abc','ab','ab','ab','abcd','abcd','abcd','ab']
df
```

Comment: No image data please

Comment: I don't understand your output, would you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
unique_count = df.loc[df['r_no']==1].groupby(['user','value'])['cam_id']\
                                     .nunique()\
                                     .rename('count_unique')

df = df.join(unique_count, on=['user','value']).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thank you @P.Tillmann This works without considering the r_no

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
(df.merge(df[df['r_no.']==1].groupby(['r_no.','user','value'])['cam_id']
                            .nunique()
                           .rename('count_unique').reset_index(), 
         on=['r_no.','user','value'], how='left').fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
   r_no.   user  value cam_id  count_unique
0      1    sam     76     ab           2.0
1      1    sam     76    abc           2.0
2      1    sam      7     ab           1.0
3      2    sam      8     ab           0.0
4      2  peter      8     ab           0.0
5      1   jack      2   abcd           1.0
6      1   jack     29   abcd           1.0
7      1   kris      2   abcd           1.0
8      2  peter      8     ab           0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

df['value_count'] = df['r_no'].value_counts()

If I understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I should check multiple conditions before value_counts tried that no luck

Comment: Then maybe reformulate your question, I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do